# Spresense SDK でTFT LCDを動かす場合

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK チュートリアルの [10. Graphics チュートリアル](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_graphics_%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB) に関して質問させてください。

以下の記述がありますが、"Arduino UNO LCD Connector board" は具体的にどのボードになりますでしょうか。

> このサンプルを動作させるには、以下のハードウェアを使う前提となっています。
>
> - Spresense Main Board
> - Spresense Extension Board
> - Arduino UNO LCD Connector board
> - ILI9341 2.2inch LCD

コントローラー IC は ILI9341 とあり、このチップはCMD/DATAのコントロールが必要だと思いますが、コンフィグメニューでその制御を有効にすると多分コンパイルが通りません。
cxd56_spi3cmddata、cxd56_spi4cmddata、cxd56_spi5cmddata　の関数が無いエラー
(エラーとなっているのは自分だけ?)

Arduino UNO LCD Connector boardというのを使えば C/Dのコントロールが必要なくなるのでしょうか。
すみませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己解決というか新たに分かったことをまとめました。
[Spresense SDK で LCD サンプルプログラムを動かしてみた その3(ほぼ完結編)](https://qiita.com/kaz19610303/items/f0b4d8198f75b23810e4)

Answer (score 0):

”Arduino UNO LCD Connector board”が何を指しているのかわかりませんが、私はそのような特定？の基板は使用しないで動かせています。SDKは最新のv2.6.0でも確認してみました。

nxdemoを例にしますが、以下のように標準のdefconfig（examples/nxdemo）を使用して、コンパイルエラーなく実行できています。

```
$tools/config.py examples/nxdemo 
$make
```

LCDとの結線情報は以下のページが参考になると思います。
[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_lcd_と拡張ボードの接続](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_lcd_%E3%81%A8%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A)

ただ現在、私はLCD（ILI9341 2.2インチ）との接続に以下の基板（※1）を利用しています。当初はジャンパーワイヤーを利用していたので、それに比べたら簡単接続可能で重宝します。
[https://kunutest.jimdofree.com/lcdsp001基板/](https://kunutest.jimdofree.com/lcdsp001%E5%9F%BA%E6%9D%BF/)

※1：LCDが2.2インチより大きいものだとそのままは使えないので注意

Comment: ありがとうございます。

もしかしてと思い、
コンフィグ設定で
SPI CMD/DATA にはチェックを入れない
LCD SPI CONNECTION はMainボードを使うので SPI5を選択
LCD ILI934x DC Pin Selection と
LCD ILI934x RST Pin Selection に接続している信号を設定

これだけの設定を変更するだけで Main Board に自作のLCDインターフェースボードを接続してLCD表示器を制御出来ました。

SPI CMD/DATA にはチェックを入れるものと思っていました。

近いうちに今回やった事をQiitaにまとめます。

Comment: なるほど、ExtensionボードにLCDを接続でなく、自作のボードをMAINボードに接続しての利用だったのですね？ConfigのBoardSelectionの設定で、Extensionの設定であったSPI4をSPI5に、GPIOは空いているものに変更して対応できたのだろうと思います。ひとまずなによりです。